# overload operator [] to give a specific index from array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, operator-overloading

I have class `XOBoard` that present an array that is size n*n,each cell of the array is an Object called `Cell`.

Each Cell object is defined by

```
class Cell {
    private:
        char ch;
    public:
        Cell(char ch = '.');
        char getCellValue();
        void setCellValue(char nch);
};
```

Board is defined this way:

```
class XOBoard {
    private:
        int n;
        Cell **Board;
};
XOBoard::XOBoard(int n) { //constructor
    this->n = (n >= 3) ? n : 3;
    Board = new Cell*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Board[i] = new Cell[n];
    }
}
```

I wanted to get to a specific Cell value by using this method: `board1[{1,2}]`, but I want to check if the values that sent to me is withing the range(n), but unfortantly I was unable to get to the Board array, and to `n` variable.

Here is the code:

```
XOBoard& operator[](list<int> list){
            int x = list.front(), y = list.back();
            return Board[x][y].getCellValue();
        }
```

Thanks a head!

Comment: The "conventional" way to do this would be to overload `operator()(int, int)` instead. Would that be in the cards for you?

Comment: "unfortantly I was unable to get to the Board array, and to n variable." what does that mean? Do you get compiler errors? Runtime errors? wrong output?

Comment: @Frank I know its not the conventional way but this is the demand from the lectur..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using `operator[]` for multidimensional subscripting is unconventional, but if you want that, you should make sure you get the correct amount of values (2 in this case) and that you return the correct type (a `Cell&` in this case).

Also be aware of [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). If you try to construct a `Board` with a value less than 3, you'll set `this->n` to 3 but go on with the construction using the erroneous `n` (that may even be a negative value).

More comments inline:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <tuple>

class Cell {
private:
    char ch;

public:
    Cell(char nch = '.') : // after the colon comes the member initializer list
        ch(nch)            // which is usually good to use
    {
        // if(ch is not valid) throw ...
    }

    char getCellValue() const { return ch; }

    // a convenient conversion operator to automatically
    // convert a Cell to a char where a char is needed
    // (like when streaming a Cell to std::cout)
    operator char() const { return ch; }

    // void setCellValue(char nch); // replaced by operator=
    Cell& operator=(char nch) {
        // if(nch is not valid) throw ...
        ch = nch;
        return *this;
    }
};

class XOBoard {
private:
    size_t n;       // use an unsigned type for sizes/indices
    Cell** Board;

public:
    // constructor
    XOBoard(size_t xy_size) :          // a member initializer list again
        n(xy_size >= 3 ? xy_size : 3), // assign to "n" here
        Board(new Cell*[n])            // the correct n is now used
    {
        // if the below construction fails, a bad_alloc will be thrown.
        // you need to add code to clean up what you've already allocated to take
        // care of that situation.
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Board[i] = new Cell[n];
        }
    }

    // Copying or moving need careful handling of the pointers.
    // Read "The rule of three/five/zero". Until then, disable it.
    XOBoard(const XOBoard&) = delete;
    XOBoard& operator=(const XOBoard&) = delete;

    // destructor
    ~XOBoard() {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) delete[] Board[i];
        delete[] Board;
    }

    // added for convenience
    size_t size() const { return n; }

    // return a Cell& and use a std::pair since you
    // expect exactly 2 values
    Cell& operator[](std::pair<size_t, size_t> pos) {
        auto& [x, y] = pos;
        if(x>=n || y>=n)
            throw std::out_of_range("{"+std::to_string(x)+","+std::to_string(y)+"}");
        return Board[x][y];
    }

};

int main() {
    try {
        XOBoard a{2};                   // trying an invalid size
        std::cout << a.size() << '\n';
        a[{2, 2}] = 'a';
        std::cout << a[{2, 2}] << '\n';
        Cell x = 'b';
        a[{2, 2}] = x;
        std::cout << a[{2, 2}] << '\n';
        a[{2, 3}] = 'c';                // index out of bounds
    } catch(const std::out_of_range& ex) {
        std::cerr << "out_of_range exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3
a
b
out_of_range exception: {2,3}
```

You should try to avoid raw pointers and actual multidimensional arrays. It's often better to emulate dimensionality by allocating a 1d array and provide an interface to the user that calculates the correct element to work on.

Comment: i've updated the code thank you!, but i `receive write access` violation on the line `ch=nch;` that in side `operator=` .

Comment: on second thought, before i want to get/set the value I want to check if the given number is smaller than n-1 to avoid run time error.

Comment: @itzikb I've never heard of `receive write access violation` but I'm pretty sure that nothing in the code I showed will cause that. Did you copy, compile and run the code in my answer? "_before i want to get/set the value I want to check if the given number is smaller than n-1_" - What do you mean? I put comments in the code where you should put your validation logic.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nXZAA4HD, Because the function need to return Cell, when the parameters that sent from outside is out range from `0-(n-1)` i get an error because its not a cell object, i want to print message to the screen that the parameter is not good.

Comment: @itzikb Ok, it's uncommon to have bounds checking in `operator[]`, but sure, it doesn't hurt (much). I strongly advice against printing messages to screen if the validation check fails though. Throw an exception that you can catch and log any way you want. I'll make an update.

Comment: Also, `pos.first-1` and `pos.second-1` is wrong. The indexing is zero-based already so no `-1` there.

Comment: And, if you decide to **not** throw an exception when you check index bounds you still would need to return a `Cell&` - or otherwise you'd have undefined behaviour. What should you then return? It becomes very ugly. You could perhaps return something like `std::optional<Cell&>` but that would force the user to check for success on every use of `operator[]`. That'd be terrible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204136/discussion-between-itzikb-and-ted-lyngmo).